# Translations editor not enabled in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, translation

I'm trying to translate a strings.xml file on Android Studio but it seems like the Translations Editor is not enabled (it does not appear as an option when I right click on the strings.xml file). I've tried deleting and installing back Android Studio but it's still the same; any ideas on how to solve?

Thank you in advance!
[this is the "no enabled action found message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTBIH.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to open the string.xml file, then you will see the open editor option on the upper right side

Comment: i cant see the screen you get, upload a screenshot

Comment: thank you for your answer, I opened the string.xml file but I don't see the open editor option, see the screen that I get https://ibb.co/4K5TQ5F... could you advise further? thanks!

Comment: I did, but still see the same icons on the upper right part and when I search the action still says it's not enabled https://ibb.co/LNLPs4Q

Comment: did you find a solution? having the same problem

Comment: This ONLY worked for me in the strings.xml file, open that one if you have multiple strings files

Answer (score 0):

Reopen the Android Studio IDE, it'll solve the problem. Also it will update the strings and refresh the layout of any layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

Translations Editor shows up when you right-click on string resource files whose names end with `strings.xml`. On others it does not. The same goes for editor option that is supposed to show up in upper right side when string resource file is opened.

So, filenames like `strings.xml`, `preferences_strings.xml`, etc. are fine, while `strings_intro.xml`, etc. are not.

In case you don't have any string resource files named in that way, you can create an empty one named `strings.xml` and use it to open Translations Editor.

Or, you can open the it in the following way:

1. Open any xml layout file
2. Switch to 'Design' view in upper right corner
3. Design toolbar will look something like the following:
   [image]
4. Click on the localizations option (globe icon)
5. At the bottom of the drop-down menu you will see 'Edit Translations...' option
6. Click on it - and there you are!