# Android Studio translation editor doesn't exist

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, editor, translation

I'm not able to open the translation editor in Android Studio as I don't see it anywhere where it should be.
When I right click on some .xml file there is no option for that. My Android Studio is a fresh installation with no changes so far. Does anyone know how to fix this?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a72J.png)

Comment: Have you seen [Localize the UI with Translations Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor)?

Comment: Of course not! Sometimes the simplest solution is the right way. You did not include informations like what is the version of AS so it was my first guess. Could you show a screen shot how editor looks like when you open `strings.xml` file?

Comment: @MichałZiober I never used Android Studio before, I installed it freshly so the version is the newest (3.3.2). I don't know what you mean by "how editor looks like", I'm not able to open the translation editor so I'm not able to provide a screenshot of that

Comment: What do you see when you open `strings.xml` file?

Comment: @MichałZiober the content of the xml file, I can edit it like with a text editor but there is no button or anything then where I am able to open the translation editor

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65831672/96313

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO community

You can open translations editor by:

1. Navigation pane (Android Preview) >> app >> res >> Double click on "strings.xml"
2. On the top right corner of the strings.xml opened window, click on "Open Editor"

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but this isn't there in my android studio
https://i.imgur.com/AspSkpZ.png

Comment: @DavidC, try to add some keys, maybe it does not show for empty file.

Comment: that something looks weird! this is also reported in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642307/translations-editor-not-enabled-in-android-studio ... I will try to figure it out

Comment: @MichałZiober the file had content, I just edited it out. I also tried xml files of another existing project of a friend who is able to open the translation editor in his project.

Comment: @DavidC not sure but try to to update NDK, SDK platform tools

Comment: @M.Zain I tried it but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidC ... I guess as long as android studio runs with no problem, then the translations editor is just a plugin attached to it. you may try to go to File > settings > Plugins > Disable and Enable potential plugins that might be relevant to this (do this by uncheck/ check again the right hand side checkbox) then close & open the android studio